# In Google App Maker, how do you display the most recent date/time on a page each time a file is uploaded with the Drive Picker button?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I am building an application in Google App Maker that upon a file upload via Drive Picker button, the page will display the date and time of the most recent upload. The part I am unsure of what to do is how to display unique date/time values on the page (reloading the page with new values each time the user uploads a file). I was going through the Google App Maker documentation, and I think it has something to do with binding label values but I am unsure of what to do with it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you not able to modify the code you use to manage the upload? I would imagine that, when the upload completes, you could then call a method to update your UI based on some parameters you supply (such as the time and a text value).

Answer (score 0):

On Drive Picket widget, you can bind events. Bind a Function on `onDocumentSelect` event. This event will be called once user has selected the document.
[image: Binding a function]

Once you have bind this function, implement the date time display logic in the function. Here's the sample.

```
//Client Script
function printJSON(widget,result)
{
  widget.datasource.item.DateField = new Date();
}
```